# Office365 SMTP Server is not getting authenticated

Tags: c#, email, smtp, office365, smtpclient

I am trying to connect to SMTP Server of **office365** but getting the below error.

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

**Below are the code for the same**

```
    public static void SendMessage()
    {

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toEmailAddress));
        msg.From = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress);
        msg.Subject = "Test Office 365 Account";
        msg.Body = "Testing email using Office 365 account.";
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Timeout = 6000000;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(msg);
    }
```

Regards,
@bjo

Comment: @RowlandShaw I saw your post. Is there any solution with this error ?

Comment: I'd not found one, as I mentioned yesterday; but there's nothing to stop you offering a bounty on the existing question (as StackOverflow discourages duplication of questions)